# how to connect amazon s3 from Oracle/Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: amazon-s3, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I want to connect to Amazon S3 from Oracle Data Integrator.
I could not find an api for Oracle Data Integrator.
How can I connect to S3 and retrieve data? Can I connect via Pl/Sql?

Answer (score 0):

from ODI we do not have any direct technology defined in the topology to connect to Amazon s3, however if i am not wrong they must be able to generate WSDL web services through which data can be accessed into ODI.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Adrian in [this Oracle Community thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4178596#thread-post-14964745):

> ODI do not natively integrate with Amazon.
>
> The only way to integrate with Amazon S3 is using CLI commands